# I need help identifying this 90(?)s TV show and episodes

Tags: story-identification, tv

I saw these shows/episodes a long time ago, in the 90s I believe.

Each of these may or may not be part of the same TV series. I believe they are part of an anthology series like The Outer Limits. It may actually be The Outer Limits, but I could not find an episode description that sounded familiar.

1. A man is in a hospital after an accident (car maybe?). I think he has a head injury. During his hospital stay, he keeps seeing a monster/alien that no one else can see. The monster will climb on top of patients and suck something (life, energy, etc.) out of them. I seem to remember the monster looking like a big mosquito.
2. A woman is a prisoner of aliens (?) and they conduct psychological tests on her. For one of the tests they give her pizza, she get really excited, starts to eat it, then finds out what's on the pizza. It's either something gross or she is allergic to it.
3. A man moves into an apartment. The landlords have strange rules. One of the rules is about not hanging pictures on the walls with nails. He finds the rules ridiculous, and starts to hang a picture using a nail. When he hammers it into the wall it starts to leak a dark liquid. There may also have been some shaking in the apartment. In the end there is a garbage chute that is actually a mouth (?), like the apartment is actually a living organism.

Comment: The thing is, I can remember #1 and #3, or something close to them and now I'm stuck, too.  Do you know for sure that they are all from the same show?

Comment: @TangoOversway I'm not sure if they are the same show or not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the [Monsters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094512/) series for the first 2 and [Tales from the Darkside](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086814/) for the last.

1. [Monsters Season 2, Episode 18 - The Offering](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0650892/)
2. [Monsters Season 2, Episode 13 - Habitat](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0650842/)
3. [Tales from the Darkside Season 2, Episode 15 - New Lease on Life](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0716921/)

Comment: All, right on the mark. Thank you so much! Were you already familiar with these episodes?

Comment: @Bryan - Most welcome! The descriptions did strike me as vaguely familiar, though I couldn't recollect them directly. I had to dig into some episode lists for shows I watched around that time that would have had similar content.